# Devextreme multiple form submitted

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular, devextreme

I am using Devextreme forms with angular 2.
I have two separate forms, but when i call submit button of first form or second form, both forms get validated. why?

[image]

Here is two different forms in html,

```
  <form action="your-action" (submit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
        <diav class="dx-fieldset">
            <div class="dx-fieldset-header">Credentials</div>
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Login</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value">
                    <dx-text-box> 
                        <dx-validator>
                            <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Login is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
                        </dx-validator>
                    </dx-text-box>
                </div>
            </div>    
                  </div>       
        <dx-validation-summary id="summary"></dx-validation-summary>        
        <dx-button 
            id="button"
            text="Register"
            type="success"  
            [useSubmitBehavior]="true">
        </dx-button>
    </form>       
    <form action="your-action" (submit)="onFormSubmit1($event)">
        <div class="dx-fieldset">
            <div class="dx-fieldset-header">Credentials</div>
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Login</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value">
                    <dx-text-box> 
                        <dx-validator>
                            <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Login is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
                        </dx-validator>
                    </dx-text-box>
                </div>
            </div>        
                  </div> 
              <dx-validation-summary id="summary"></dx-validation-summary>
                <dx-button 
            id="button"
            text="Register"
            type="success"  
            [useSubmitBehavior]="true">
        </dx-button>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you please share your code? its difficult to understand from screenshot.

Comment: @RajkishorSahu : have added some html code

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation `[useSubmitBehavior]="true"` will validate and submit html form. You will need to set `validation group` to group your form controls and then button onClick you can execute `DevExpress.validationEngine.validateGroup(group);` to validate your from controls. Adding link to the document.

[validate group doc](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidationGroup/)